# Shortcut of zooming out in Windows in Parallels Desktop

Tags: windows-10, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I have a french keyboard. I try to use Windows 10 via `Parallels Desktop` under Mac.

In Mac, in Chrome we use `cmd + =` and `cmd + -` to zoom in and zoom out. It is the same in VS Code.

But in Windows, it does not work well:

1) in Chrome, `control + -` can zoom in, whereas I have not found the shortcut to zoom out.

2) in VS Code, `control + -` can zoom in, whereas I have not found the shortcut to zoom out. In the setting it is written that the shortcut for zooming out is `control + NumPad_Subtract`, but what is the key?

Could anyone help?

Comment: See this Lifehacker page for [zoom controls](https://lifehacker.com/5815125/how-to-zoom-in-and-out-on-a-web-page)

Comment: I tried in OP, it does not work... @spike_66

Comment: You should be able to customize shortcuts in Parallels Desktop > Preferences > Shortcuts